# Why there is no inverse function for gmtime in libc?

Tags: time, posix, libc

In libc there are two functions to convert from system time to calendar time - `gmtime` and `localtime`, but only `localtime` has inverse function - `mktime`. Why there is no inverse function for `gmtime`, and if there shouldn't be any, why `gmtime` exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain the existence of `gmtime()`, some context is required:

`gmtime()` will convert a *timestamp* representation (number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`) to **broken-down time representation** (aka, `struct tm`), assuming that the *timestamp* timezone is **UTC**:

> The `gmtime()` function converts the calendar time timep  to 
>   broken-down time representation, expressed in **Coordinated Universal
>   Time (UTC)**.  It may return NULL when the year does not fit into an
>   integer.  The return value  points to a statically allocated struct
>   which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date 
>   and  time  functions.

In the other hand, `localtime()` takes in consideration the [local] system timezone (including daylight saving):

> The `localtime()` function converts the calendar time  timep  to 
>   broken- down  time  representation,  expressed relative to the user's
>   specified timezone.  The function acts as if it  called  `tzset(3)`  and
>   sets  the external  variables tzname with information about the
>   current timezone, timezone **with the difference between Coordinated
>   Universal  Time  (UTC) and  local standard time in seconds**, and
>   daylight to a nonzero value if daylight savings time rules apply
>   during some part of  the  year.

Note that the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` differ from timezone to timezone (when it was `1970-01-01 00:00:00` in New York, it clearly wasn't in, for instance, Tokyo).

The `mktime()` converts a `struct tm` to a `time_t` value (number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00`) based on the [local] system timezone, and *should* not be interpreted as the *inverse* of any particular function (such as `localtime()` or `gmtime()`), as the *inverse* term may be [wrongly] interpreted as a safe cross-system conversion:

> The  `mktime()` function **converts a broken-down time structure**,
>   expressed as local time, to calendar time representation.  The 
>   function  ignores the  values  supplied  by the caller in the tm_wday
>   and tm_yday fields. The value specified in the tm_isdst field informs
>   mktime()  whether  or not  daylight  saving  time (DST) is in effect
>   for the time supplied in the tm structure: a positive value means DST
>   is in effect;

There is also a non-portable function (for GNU and BSD systems) called `timegm()`, which assumes a UTC timezone, such as `gmtime()` does.

**References**

Blockquoted text is retrieved from parts of release 3.74 of the Linux man-pages project.

Comment: By "inverse" I mean that if we take a certain timestamp X, then X = mktime(localtime(X)), but there is no such function F, that X = F(gmtime(X)), and my question is why F does not exist in libc.

Comment: you can still use `mktime()` for that, but you need to add or subtract the UTC offset from the returned value.

Comment: I can use `localtime` instead of `gmtime` the same way. Then why `gmtime` exists?

Comment: You can also use the non-portable extension (only on GNU and BSD systems) called `timegm()`

Comment: Since `gmtime()` *ignores* the local timezone, it's perfect to handle UTC time values, which is a common timezone in applications to be depoyed (and sync'd) around the globe.

Comment: Anyway, this may become a *primarly* opinion based discussion, as there are other methods to process such timestamps and keep the values coherent.

Comment: BTW, is `mktime` fully equivalent to `timelocal`? And does `timegm` ignore the local timezone?

Comment: The man page claims so [for both questions]. It also provides a portable alternative to use `mktime()` without converting UTC time [structs] to local time [structs]. They explicit use the term `inverse` [which I don't really agree with that term as it may be misleading or ambiguous]

Answer (score 7):

I've found this piece of code work satisfactorily:

```
namespace std_ext {
    time_t timegm(tm* _Tm) 
    {
        auto t = mktime(_Tm);
        return t + (mktime(localtime(&t)) - mktime(gmtime(&t)));
    }
}
```

which satifies the test:

```
auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
auto t2 = std_ext::timegm(std::gmtime(&t1));
EXPECT_EQ(t1, t2);
```

Comment: What if `mktime(localtime(&t))` and `mktime(gmtime(&t))` straddle a daylight saving time change?

Comment: I have no idea. That might indeed be a corner case not handled.

Comment: Considering it's UB to put your own symbols into `std` (https://stackoverflow.com/q/37541022/1601448) I suggest you put it in another namespace (like global, but global con conflict with one in Linux/BSD systems). Probably best to just call it time_to_gm or something.

Answer (score 0):

This rather complicated solution explains succinctly why it is hard to create the inverse.  All integer math and has been verified for every day between years -1468014 and 1471731 to be the inverse of gmtime.  The full range of 64 bit input check would take about two years effort.

```
/**
 * Inverse of struct std::tm * std::gmtime( const std::time_t * t )
 * @param t input calendar date
 * @param gregorian indication stored calendar date is Gregorian (true) or Julian (false)
 * @return number of seconds since 1970 Jan 1 00:00:00 (whichever timezone of the input)
 */
std::time_t posix_time( const struct std::tm * t, bool gregorian = true )
{
    std::time_t days,t1,t2,t3,m;
    m = (17L - t->tm_mon)>>4L; // [0,1]
    t1 = 1461L*(t->tm_year) + (((489L*t->tm_mon + 9L)>>4L)<<2L)+(7L*m)+60120L;
    days = (t1/4L) - (((t1<0L) && (t1%4L))?1L:0L) + t->tm_mday - 40587L;
    if( gregorian )
    {
        t2 = t->tm_year + 1900L - m;
        t3 = 8 - 3*(t2/100L) + (((t2<0L) && (t2%100L))?3L:0L);
        days += (t3/4L) - (((t3<0L) && (t3%4L))?1L:0L);
    }

    return ((days*24L+t->tm_hour)*60L+t->tm_min)*60L+t->tm_sec;
}
```