# mktime returning the wrong time

Tags: c++, c++11, time, mktime

I have two functions for creating a date string, and parsing a date string. The creation works, but the parser seems to add 5 hours to the time. For context, my time zone is EST, 5 hours behind GMT. How can this be fixed? Below are the functions:

```cpp
std::string build_date(time_t rawtime) {
    struct tm* timeinfo = gmtime(&rawtime);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale(setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")));
    ss << std::put_time(timeinfo, "%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z");
    return ss.str();
}

time_t parse_date(const std::string& date) {
    struct tm timeinfo = {0};
    std::istringstream ss(date);
    ss.imbue(std::locale(setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")));
    ss >> std::get_time(&timeinfo, "%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z");
    return mktime(&timeinfo);
}
```

Comment: Suggest setting the proper locale.

Comment: `mktime` is the inverse of `localtime`, _not_ `gmtime`

Comment: I don't see `%Z` listed in the [documentation for `std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) so likely your time zone is being ignored.

Comment: @paddy Then what is the inverse of gmtime?

Comment: See [Why there is no inverse function for gmtime in libc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38298359/1553090)

Comment: It's a real nuisance that you can't do this, whatever the rationale might be.

Comment: You can do this in C++20 using chrono.  Or with my C++20 chrono preview library using C++11/14/17.