# C++ When is it OK to extend the `std` namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, std

A thread on SO says that [extending `std` is UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541022/what-are-the-reasons-that-extending-the-std-namespace-is-considered-undefined-be) (ok, unless you're the standard writers of course). But from time to time, `std` is happily extended. When is it OK to do so?

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320798/adding-types-to-the-std-namespace

Comment: @NathanOliver related, but not a dupe. I would be surprised though if this is an entirely new question. But it's definitely a good one.

Comment: What you can definitely do is to provide specialisations for certain templates, for example `std::numeric_limits<my_own_number_type>`.

Comment: You can add specialization of your type for the ones from std which expect it.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think the part **the ones from `std` which expect it** nails it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only case where it is OK to add a definition into the `std` namespace is specialization of a template that already exists in the namespace and to explicitly instantiate a template. However, only if they depend on a user defined type.

[[namespace.std]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std) (standard draft):

> 1. The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.
> 2. The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares
>
>    (2.1) an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template, or
>
>    (2.2) an explicit specialization of any member function template of a standard library class or class template, or
>
>    (2.3) an explicit or partial specialization of any member class template of a standard library class or class template.
>
>    A program may explicitly instantiate a template defined in the standard library only if the declaration depends on the name of a user-defined type and the instantiation meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

---

As an example of standard templates that are explicitly designed to be extended for user defined types: `std::hash` and `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: Thanks, I was about to ask from @Jarod42 the list of "the ones from `std` which expect it" but this is good enough.

Comment: I extend `std` namespace with `make_unique` function for c++11 as it is written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11). Is this okay?

Comment: @Walter I replaced the cppreference quotes by the ones from the standard draft.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy no, adding a new function to `std` namespace is not OK. See the standard quote [namespace.std]/1

Comment: Note that C++20 further restricts specializations, forbidding them for function templates in particular.

Answer (score 2):

You can put template specializations for your custom data types.

As example: your own specialzations of `std::hash` for `std::unordered_map`