# How to correctly shim functionality into std?

Tags: c++, std

I recently switched from the Microsoft compiler to GCC. Among many things, I noticed that `std::make_unique` became unavailable. This is apparently because `make_unique` is not part of C++11 standard, and Microsoft just happened to include it as an extension.

We are planning to move to C++14 soon, but in the mean while I wrote this "shim" function, and put it into `std`.

```cpp
namespace std
{
    template<typename T, typename... TArgs>
    unique_ptr<T> make_unique(TArgs&&... args)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));
    }
}
```

This solved that problem on gcc. However, I imagine it would cause problems back at Microsoft's side, since it would be a duplicate definition.

Is there a way to correctly shim functionality into std, so that it wouldn't cause trouble on different compilers / C++ standards? I looked around and didn't come up with anything. I thought maybe something like an include guard, for specific standard functions?

```cpp
#ifndef MAKE_UNIQUE_DEFINED
#define MAKE_UNIQUE_DEFINED
// Define make_unique
#endif
```

Sadly it seems `std` doesn't define include guards for specific functions. Is there anything else I can do to make this more correct and compiler / c++ standard agnostic?

Comment: technically, §17.4.3.1 makes it impossible to portably insert functionality into the `std` namespace, apart from template specializations

Comment: In "theory", I would expect that this is not allowed according to the standard, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41062439/417197 or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std. Of course, in practice, it will work fine.

Comment: The MSVC version you were using probably already supported that C++14 feature by default. If you are using a new MSVC version, you can explicitly specify which C++ version you want (starting from 14).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, actually. Just turn the two conditions you mentioned in your post to a conditional macro definition:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && __cplusplus == 201103L
#  define MAKE_UNIQUE_DEFINED 1
#endif
```

- `_MSC_VER` checks the TU is compiled with MSVC. [It's one of their predefined macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). You can use it to further refine the check, since it's the encoded version number of MSVC.
- [201103L is the value of `__cplusplus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) when the TU is compiled as C++11 (this is standard, across platforms).
- In case `__cplusplus` isn't correctly defined for you (because Microsoft), you can use the `_MSVC_LANG` macro in its stead.

The above can be used to wrap your "shim", as you originally planned. Or any other MSVC extension that pertains to these versions, as a matter of fact.

---

As an alternative, to avoid reopening the `std` namespace (a no-no). You could use namespacing to have the definition present in a safe place, and control how your program interprets it:

```
namespace extended_std {
  #ifdef MAKE_UNIQUE_DEFINED
    inline namespace
  #else
    namespace
  #endif
  shim {
     // your definition goes here
  }

  #ifndef MAKE_UNIQUE_DEFINED
  using std::make_unique;
  #endif
}
```

The macro is then only there to control what `extended_std::make_unique` refers to. It either makes the namespace `inline`, pouring its content into the enclosing one. Or adds a using declaration for `std::make_unique`.

Comment: What's the point of having just the keyword `inline` conditionally compiled?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Keeping the OP's version available for referral if they need it on the else branch, for reaons.

Comment: there is also the predefined `__cpp_lib_make_unique` for this purpose

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think of `inline` namespace. I think you'd better make that explicit, `inline namespace` versus `namespace`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - I only conditionally compile the inline keyword, to control the namespace being inlined. There are various alternatives of course. One can avoid the namespace altogether and conditionally compile the entire definition.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - And to be honest, I'm not sure which alternative is best for the OP. This is just the one that came to mind to allow some more refined versioning. It could be utter rubbish of course.

Comment: You mean microsoft actually sets `__cplusplus` to the C++11 value? That must be recent.

Comment: @MarcGlisse - I know Microsofts track record with standard conformance, but this isn't a particularly hard one to do. My shop uses it to check for features.

Comment: It isn't that it's hard, it is a matter of policy, they were waiting until their C++11 support was complete to change the value of the macro, and there are still some features missing.

Comment: @MarcGlisse - Regardless of MSVC version, I added a note about `_MSVC_LANG` just in case.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, do not define new functionality into `std`. Define the function elsewhere and arrange to conditionally make it available per the other answer. Often for things like this, it is easier to get it from your own namespace on all platforms until all the compilers catch up. You will need to have some mechanism to manage the declarations and using statements for compatibility functions. (Another traditional approach is to use something like autoconfigure to sniff the compilation environment and custom build compatibility headers for your application. This is rather ugly but when done well it results in high levels of portability.)

For an industrial strength library which aims provide new C++ features in not quite up-to-date compilation environments, there is Abseil: https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp . The design decisions there are good to look at if you are interested in doing something robust for a significant project.

Answer (score 4):

There is a predefined macro for this purpose: `__cpp_lib_make_unique`
See [feature test macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/User:D41D8CD98F/feature_testing_macros)

The following *should* be perfectly portable:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

#ifdef __cpp_lib_make_unique

namespace lib {
    using std::make_unique;
}

#else

namespace lib {
    template<typename T, typename... TArgs>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(TArgs&&... args)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...));
    }
}

#endif
```

You end up having `make_unique` in another namespace, `lib`
in this example, but that is necessary for strict conformance
(see [§17.4.3.1](http://www.lcdf.org/c%2B%2B/clause17.html))

I say *should* because, unfortunately, MSVC does not define those
macros, so you have to use `_MSC_VER` for MS specific things.

Comment: You mean Microsoft started defining those macros? That must be recent.

Comment: "MSVS" (Microsoft Visual Studio) should probably be "MSVC" (Microsoft Visual C/C++ Compiler).