# Is it possible to add own constructor for std::array type?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdvector, stdarray, constructor-overloading

I tried to add my own constructor for `std::array` type, but I don't sure is it possible and how to do that...

I tried sth like this:

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;

namespace std {
  template<std::size_t _Nm>
  array::array(std::vector<byte_t> data)
  {
    // Some content
  }
}
```

I want to create very easy mechanism to converting `std::vector<byte_t>` to `std::array<byte_t, size>`.

1. It is possible?
2. How can I do that?

I am using C++14 (and I cannot use in my project newer standards)

Comment: Just FYI, adding things to std namespace is usually UB.

Comment: @user202729 Is it always UB? Even if I tried to adapt standard data container for my own defined types?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062294/c-when-is-it-ok-to-extend-the-std-namespace

Comment: It would be simpler to write a function like `make_array` that returns the array and takes the vector as argument

Comment: There is a very limited number of cases when adding code to `namespace std` is allowed. That's irrelevant because you cannot add a constructor to a class you don't own, in `namespace std` or not. FYI `std::array` has no constructors *by design*.

Comment: there is no such thing as *sometimes UB*. UB = UB. It is a bit weird what your are trying to achieve. std::array is created at compile time, while vector is created at run-time (and doesnt have a constexpr constructor). I have the feeling there is another problem under your question.

Comment: I only try to achieve very simple converting vector to array. As simple as `char c = 10`. If I cannot add constructor, I would like to add `operator=`.

Comment: You cannot add `operator=` either, because it's special, but you can add some other operator, such as `<<` (in your own namespace).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is wrong with `std::vector` for you?

Comment: @DanielLangr It is partially true what you said. Actually it is possible as it is presented by MaximEgorushkin. I need fixed sized container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructors are special member functions, they must be declared within the class definition. It is not possible to add constructors to an existing class without changing the class definition.

You can achieve a similar effect using a factory function:

```
template<size_t N, class T>
std::array<T, N> as_array(std::vector<T> const& v) {
    std::array<T, N> a = {};
    std::copy_n(v.begin(), std::min(N, v.size()), a.begin());
    return a;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<byte_t> v;
    auto a = as_array<10>(v);
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that a `vector`'s size is known at runtime but `array`'s must be known at compile-time...

Comment: @ildjarn I know that, and I have a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the necessity of such a conversion, at the exception of a function which expect a std::array and cannot be modified. You have two alternatives :

1. [Use the good old T* raw array underneath the vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923272/how-to-convert-vector-to-array). After all, std::array is designed to easily manage the equivalent of a fixed-size C array.
2. Make your code unaware of containers by using functions on iterators. This is design path the modern c++ expect. You can take a look at the possible implementation of [various operations in the algorithm library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).