# How to reset filesystem::current_path() in C++17?

Tags: c++, directory, std-filesystem

I am writing a C++ program in which I change the working directory with `std::filesystem::current_path(working_directory)`, where `working_directory` is a string. Is there a good way to, later in the program, reset the working directory to its original value? I understand that one solution would be to use a variable `string initial_directory = std::filesystem::current_path()` before I change the working directory and then later reset it with `std::filesystem::current_path(initial_directory)`, but I feel like there should be a more elegant solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Save it and set it back is the only way I know to do it.

Comment: I know of nothing in filesystem that does what you want and wouldn't expect it to exist. C++ has a policy of not making you pay for stuff you didn't ask for, and caching the original value of the working directory so that it can be restored later would be a cost that all users of filesystem would have to pay whether they needed it or not. There might be a target-specific API call that does this, but for portability's sake caching the original value and restoring it as needed seems the most-sane option.

Answer (score 1):

DIY?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <stack>

static std::stack<std::filesystem::path> s_path;
void pushd(std::filesystem::path path) {
    s_path.push(std::filesystem::current_path());
    std::filesystem::current_path(path);
}
void popd() {
    if (!s_path.empty()) {
        std::filesystem::current_path(s_path.top());
        s_path.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Current path is " << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';
    pushd(std::filesystem::temp_directory_path());
    std::cout << "Current path is " << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';
    popd();
    std::cout << "Current path is " << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';
    popd();
    std::cout << "Current path is " << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: There is zero reason to do it in `namespace std`, it just creates unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat confusion aside, it indicates that you are pushing something related to the file system.

Comment: It also [causes undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/library#namespace.std-1) (which is mostly a formality here, but still).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - thinking about it, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062294/c-when-is-it-ok-to-extend-the-std-namespace; taking it back, will update the answer