# optional and variant with gcc 4.7

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost

I have code that should be compiled with gcc 4.7,
which have not bad c++11 supports, but lacks c++14 and c++17.

And I want to use `std::optional` and `std::variant` in my code,
with fallback for `boost::optional` and `boost::variant` for gcc 4.7

What the standard way to achieve this?

I see two variants:

1. Wrapper around variant, it may be macro like: `#define VARIANT_TYPE boost::variant` or `namespace my_code { using variant = boost::variant }`
2. extend `std` namespace

The first one is not good, because of my code will use `my_code::variant`,
instead of `std::variant`. The second one looks more clear for me.

The `2` may be UB in general case [What are the reasons that extending the std namespace is considered undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541022/what-are-the-reasons-that-extending-the-std-namespace-is-considered-undefined-be)

But what about my specific case? I know what exactly version of `gcc` has `variant/optional`, I can check it on configure stage of build. For all other compilers/standard c++ library I can require c++17 support and not use my hack that convert `boost::optional` to `std::optional`.

Can I still catch some exotic problems?

Comment: What's the point of switching implementations? Just use boost unconditionally.

Comment: I would do `using variant_type = std::variant;`. Avoid a macro for this. Also you should never extend `std` except where the standard allows.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Because of it is library, and I do not want create external dependency on boost for users who has `c++17` compatible compilers.

Comment: @Galik But for specific compiler and libstdc++ not for general case

Answer (score 3):

You might use something like:

```
#ifdef NEED_WORKAROUND

# include <boost/optional.hpp>
# include <boost/variant.hpp>

namespace workaround
{
    namespace std
    {
        using boost::optional;
        using boost::variant;
    }
}
using namespace workaround;
#else
# include <optional>
# include <variant>
#endif
```

So usage with `::std::variant<..>` won't work
but simple `std::variant<..>` would mostly behave similar (you might have issue with ADL).

Comment: Why would you have any issues with ADL? `using`-declarations don't influence ADL in any way. `using`-directives only influence it in so far that they might bring names into scope that are *not* ADL associated (like when calling functions for primitive types that have no associated namespaces)

Comment: @sehe: for example for code like: `find(carray, carray+N, std::optional<int>(42))` we don't need `std::find` (without the workaround, but we need it with). So there is an "issue".

Answer (score 1):

One way to get close to what you want is to find a library that does it for you.

For example, [Google's Abseil](https://abseil.io/about/) does this. Unfortunately, their [Supported Platforms](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/platforms/platforms#linux) page shows that they need gcc 4.8+, as they require C++11. But if you can meet their requirements, then you can use `absl::optional` in place of `std::optional`, and if `std::optional` exists, then `absl::optional` is `std::optional`, otherwise it would be equivalent to `std::optional`.

That you write `absl::optional` instead of `std::optional` is inconsequential; readers of your codebase can easily learn that they are "the same thing." I strongly recommend not trying to put this into the `std` namespace.

---

Doing this yourself is unpleasant, but not impossible. You'd need 2 things:

- A way to tell if `std::optional` exists
- An implementation of `std::optional` in another namespace that works on the version of the compiler you want to support (note that the `boost` versions aren't necessarily completely equivalent to the `std` versions)

Then, you could write your workaround like in Option 1, and write something like:

```
#if STD_OPTIONAL_EXISTS

namespace compat {
    template <typename... Ts>
    using optional = std::optional<Ts...>;
}

#else

namespace compat {
    template <typename... Ts>
    using optional = boost::optional<Ts...>;
}

#endif
```