# How should I make std::filesystem appear standards-conforming to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, std-filesystem

I have a project that is currently locked into Visual Studio 2015. However, I want to write code that is as standards-conforming as possible.

I want to use `std::filesystem` but it didn't make it into the standard until C++-17. Fortunately, just about everything is available, just in the `std::experimental::filesystem::v1` namespace. I'm not a fan of blanket `using` directives; I prefer to scope things fully to make it clear where the thing comes from. So I'm not going to just put in a global `using` statement. Some magic is required to convince the compiler to do what I want.

This was my first attempt:

```
#include <filesystem>
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER <= 1900 // VS 2015
namespace std {
    namespace filesystem {
        using path = std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path;
    }
}
#endif
```

That works pretty well, and `std::filesystem::path` is now accessible. I've tested creating and using `path` objects and it works.

As I move forward, I know I'm going to need more stuff. I wondered if there might be a way to just bring in the whole thing:

```
namespace std {
    namespace filesystem {
        using std::experimental::filesystem::v1;
    }
}
```

That seemed like a step backwards. Nothing appears to be visible. In hindsight, I guess it makes sense, since the scope of the `using` statement ends with the closing brace on the next line.

Next, I want to get a `directory_entry`. The same technique seems to work

```
namespace std {
    namespace filesystem {
        using directory_entry = std::experimental::filesystem::v1::directory_entry;
    }
}
```

Again, the compiler seems happy.

Now, I want to use `std::directory::create_directories`. However, this is a function, not a class, so the same technique won't work.

I thought that `std::function` might be tailor made for this, but I'm not having any luck. I tried

```
namespace std {
    namespace filesystem {
        function<bool(path)> create_directories = std::experimental::filesystem::v1::create_directories;
    }
}
```

and the compiler says

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'std::function<bool (std::filesystem::path)>'
```

There are two overloads of the function (one takes a second argument to return an error code rather than throwing an exception).

I'm stuck. This has to be possible but my C++-foo is weak.

Comment: I think extending the `std` namespace is undefined behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541022/what-are-the-reasons-that-extending-the-std-namespace-is-considered-undefined-be

Comment: @MFisherKDX I understand that, and undefined means undefined. But if you substitute `foo` for `std` the behavior would be the same. And in this case, I consider extending it justified, since the symbols I'm adding are in a later version of the standard.

Comment: I don't suppose `using std::filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem::v1` works?

Comment: @jwm .. ok, I understand.  Can you cast the function first like in this example?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393285/stdfunction-fails-to-distinguish-overloaded-functions

Comment: Got it ... had to dig a bit deeper in the answers, but you pointed me to the right place

Comment: @MarkRansom Would be `namespace std { namespace filesystem = experimental::filesystem::v1; }` but I like the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in the error message, and the help required to instantiate `std::function` for an overloaded method. Thanks to [MFisherKDX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8767209/mfisherkdx) for pointing me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393285/stdfunction-fails-to-distinguish-overloaded-functions) and to [W.F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4324224/w-f) for the answer there that works.

Ignoring the question of whether it is legal, moral, or in good taste to extend the standard namespace (because in this case I believe it is at least 2 of the 3), here's my fully commented work-around:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER <= 1900
// Visual Studio 2015 work-around ... 
// std::filesystem was incorporated into C++-17 (which is obviously after VS
// 2015 was released). However, Microsoft implemented the draft standard in
// the std::exerimental namespace. To avoid nasty ripple effects when the
// compiler is updated, make it look like the standard here
#include <functional>
namespace std {
  namespace filesystem {
    using directory_entry = std::experimental::filesystem::v1::directory_entry;
    using directory_iterator = std::experimental::filesystem::v1::directory_iterator;
    function<bool(path const&)> create_directories = 
        static_cast<bool(*)(path const&)>(
            std::experimental::filesystem::v1::create_directories);
  }
}
#endif
```

UPDATE: [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8922/sebastian-redl) had the simplest solution.

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER <= 1900
// Visual Studio 2015 work-around ... 
// std::filesystem was incorporated into C++-17 (which is obviously after VS
// 2015 was released). However, Microsoft implemented the draft standard in
// the std::exerimental namespace. To avoid nasty ripple effects when the
// compiler is updated, make it look like the standard here
namespace std {
  namespace filesystem = experimental::filesystem::v1;
}
#endif
```

By the way, gcc 7.3 requires nearly exactly the same work-around, except you can't

```
#include <filesystem>
```

but must

```
#include <experimental/filesystem>
```

instead