# Why isn't `std::hash` a customization point by overload as `std::begin`?

Tags: c++, hash, overloading, partial-specialization, customization-point

As the title says, `std::begin`, `std::end`, `std::swap`, etc, are very well known `std` "customization points" (functions meant to be found by ADL). However, `std::hash` is, I think, the only std behaviour customizable by the user that implies to (A) open `std` namespace (B) create a partial specialization.

Why hasn't `std::hash` being designed as a customization point like the other ones, by overloading a function instead of partial specializing a class?

Comment: Historical reasons, I guess.  Same way as `std::less`, etc.

Comment: Also, to the best of my knowledge, `std::distance` is not a CPO at all.  And `std::begin` itself is not either; `std::ranges::begin` is.

Comment: I'll have to check that, but for your benefit, the C++11 and C++14 final drafts are available at https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/ and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/

Comment: BTW, where does the standard library take a container?  Because I didn't seem to find any.

Comment: @L.F. iterator adaptors like `insert_iterator` takes them. `std::stack`, `std::queue` and `std::priority_queue` depends on them, and range-based loops are implemented by enabling ADL on `begin` and `end`: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/stmt.ranged#1.3

Comment: Are you sure `ostream_iterator` calls `begin` or `end`?

Comment: I edited the comment 15 minutes ago. I mistyped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199131/discussion-between-l-f-and-peregring-lk).

Comment: @L.F. Question edited. I say this in a comment to reflect that our discussion refers to a previous version of the question.

Comment: I think you're getting this all wrong.  Neither `std::hash` nor `std::begin` are customization points.  To allow your usertype to work with `std::begin` you simply add a `begin()` member function to it.  For `std::hash` the situation is different.  This is simply the default implementation of the hasher used in standard containers and the customization point is the `Hash` template argument of the container, not prying open `namespace std` and specializing `std::hash`.

Comment: @HenriMenke `begin` is always called in a ADL-friendly manner. This is basically the definition of a customization point.

Answer (score 1):

You have been taken in by a common misconception, but `std::hash` is *not a customization point* for hashing of user-defined types.  Instead, `std::hash` is the default implementation of the hasher that is used by the standard containers.  If you want to use the standard containers with user-defined types, then you should use their template arguments to supply a hasher.

## Correct

All standard containers that require a hash function for their contents have a template argument that takes a function object whose call operator computes the hash.

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Point { int x, y; };

struct PointHasher {
    size_t operator()(Point const &p) {
        size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(seed, p.x);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, p.y);
        return seed;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<Point, PointHasher> m;
}
```

## Wrong

Writing into `namespace std` is usually *undefined behaviour*, see also [What are the reasons that extending the std namespace is considered undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541022)  There is an exception for template specializations under certain circumstances, but in this case it is not even necessary.

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Point { int x, y; };

namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<Point> {
        size_t operator()(Point const &p) {
            size_t seed = 0;
            boost::hash_combine(seed, p.x);
            boost::hash_combine(seed, p.y);
            return seed;
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<point> m;
}
```

Comment: By marking the common and recommended approach as Wrong, you are excluding the possibility of providing a default hash function for the standard unordered associative containers.  `std::hash` is designed like this for a reason.

Comment: It's allowed by the standard to add user specializations for `std` function or class templates as far as it depends on user-defined types.

Answer (score 0):

Like `std::less`, `std::hash` is meant to be a function object.  For example, [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) takes a `Hash` template argument:

```
template <
    class Key                            ,
    class Hash      = std::hash<Key>     , // function object type
    class KeyEqual  = std::equal_to<Key> ,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class unordered_set;
```

That's why `std::hash` is a class template instead of a function template.  You can specialize `std::hash` and make `unordered_set` default to using it, or you can provide your own hash function object.

Comment: You should add that the customization point is the `Hash` template argument and not prying open `namespace std` and specializing `std::hash` for `Key`.

Comment: “You can specialize `std::hash` and make `unordered_set` default to using it” No, you can't.  Writing stuff into `namespace std` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @HenriMenke Specilizing `std::hash` is _not_ undefined.  The standard makes an allowance for specializing standard library class templates for user-defined types.  See [namespace.std](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.std#2).

Comment: The standard makes allowance to specialize any std template free function (not member functions) or template class as far as it depends on user defined types. This includes `std::hash`.